# how to get single row each time from database using linq and multiview control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, multiview

I am creating a project called Online Exam Portal. In which Student can select `Technology` and give exam. Student can select technology from dropdownlist.

Questions for particular Technology are coming from database. Now i want single question at a time in a view (of MultiView control), that is, when student clicks Next Button then only second question should be display in same view.
I am able to retrieve one question but not ahead.

I have tried Following code:

ScheduleExam.Aspx :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box-body">


                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:MultiView ID="mvExam" runat="server">
                        <asp:View ID="viewTech" runat="server">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTechnology" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2"></asp:DropDownList><br /><br />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSchedule" Text="Schedule" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSchedule_Click" runat="server" />
                        </asp:View>
                        <asp:View ID="viewTest" runat="server">
                           <asp:Label ID="lblQtnNum" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbOpt1" runat="server" /><br />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbOpt2" runat="server" /><br />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbOpt3" runat="server" /><br /><br />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next" /> 
                        </asp:View>
                    </asp:MultiView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ScheduleExam.aspx.cs :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            mvExam.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
            {
                var qry = from i in dt.Technologies
                          select i;

                ddlTechnology.DataSource = qry;
                ddlTechnology.DataTextField = "TechnologyName";
                ddlTechnology.DataValueField = "TechnologyId";
                ddlTechnology.DataBind();
                ddlTechnology.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Technology", ""));
            }
        }
    }




protected void btnSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var qry = from i in dt.Questions
                      where i.TechnologyId == ddlTechnology.SelectedIndex
                      select i;
            Session["Question"] = qry.FirstOrDefault();
            Session["Qt_Cnt"] = 1;
            mvExam.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
            foreach (var item in qry)
            {
                lblQtnNum.Text = Session["Qt_Cnt"].ToString();
                lblQuestion.Text = item.Question1;
                rdbOpt1.Text = item.Option1;
                rdbOpt2.Text = item.Option2;
                rdbOpt3.Text = item.Option3;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

I have searched on internet but couldn't find any fruitful results. Comment if any information lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Skip()` and `Take()` on your query :

```
        var qry = (from i in dt.Questions
                  where i.TechnologyId == ddlTechnology.SelectedIndex
                  select i).Skip(currentPage).Take(1);
```

Then you add the `currentPage` variable to your class and increment it in the *Next page* button handler. And of course the *Next page* button handler must reexecute the code you have in the `btnSchedule_Click` method.

Note that in my example `currentPage` must be zero-based (first page is 0, not 1)

Comment: so there are no modifications in foreach loop right? i mean use of break; statement. ?